# In Godot browser game, is it possible to let the player download a file?

Tags: godot, browser

I have a Godot game exported to the browser. I want to let the player export some data and let it save the data as a file on their PC, as if they were downloading a file from the Web. Is it possible for me to do that?

Comment: [What does your research so far tell you](https://godotforums.org/discussion/21301/html5-download-file)?

Comment: Do you also want to have the game access that file once downloaded? What is that file exactly, why would they want to download it?